# Wordpress and AJAX - including wp-blog-header breaks the call

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax.php file in my Wordpress themes folder, and this was working fine on the DEV server. However, when I moved it to another server, the script that I have written no longer works... bizarre!

Im now rolling back to try and find the problem, but its most annoying because the very same version works on another server?!

Here's the code (for what its worth...)

**Javascript Call:**

```
   function change_event(ID){
     //alert("ID: "+ID);   
     $.post('wp-content/themes/muni/ajaxcalls.php', 
     { id: ID }, 
     function(data){
       alert('complete: '+data);
       //$('#showingevent').html(data);
     });     
   }
```

**ajaxcalls.php**

```
require_once("../../../wp-blog-header.php");  
global $more;
```

At this point, it breaks. There is no point including the code I have written after the require. If I comment this line, the code below works.

If I browse directly to the ajaxcalls.php file, I get the results I am expecting, but it will not feed back to the success function of the ajax call.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers SO!

Tom

edit: I'm firing change_event using this:

```
   $('.eventoption A').click(function(ev){
     ev.preventDefault();
     change_event($(this).attr('id'));
     clearInterval(timer);
   });
```

I've also updated the change_event() function to reflect the one that I'm using rather than the debug that I was using before.

**The problem happens as soon as I include the wp-blog-header.php file.**

Comment: i think you should try `$("#container").load("ajaxcalls.php")` to load the data directly into the div, you say that when you visit the page you see the content, that tells me that the `"id=" + ID` is causing the data to be changed as your not sending POST Data when your directly landing on the page.

Comment: The ajaxcalls.php file gets all the wordpress posts anyway, but if you pass an ID to it, it will only return the post you want. This is why I get a return with POST data.

Comment: How are you firing change_event()? What is the full URL to ajaxcalls.php?

Comment: I've updated the post. It's fired using links that have the post ID set as the ID on the link

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is error reporting on?

Comment: tried that one too... I don't get any errors :( I get errors if I change the path to the wp-blog-header file because it can't find it. But when it includes the file, I don't get any feedback

Comment: @RobertPitt I took what you said and tried something different, this time... I am using the $.get function with jQuery and just calling the index file of the wordpress site. Then, in the theme single.php I have an IF statement that checks for the $_GET variable, if it's present, it gives a stripped down version of the page so that the ajax call can put the content in a DIV. 

Still don't understand why the previous method worked perfectly on a different server, but there you go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick was to include **wp-load.php** instead of **wp-blog-header.php**

Comment: Then is must be any typo or so. The fun part: `wp-blog_header.php` does nothing else than loading `wp-load.php`, instantiate wordpress and then load `template-loader.php`

Comment: wp-load is the proper way to to include WP as it loads the theme etc. blog header doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

use this. It is working on localhost, and i hope it will also work for live server.

1. First get the folder name of the root directory of your site

`$folder = substr(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1), 0, 
    strpos(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1), "/"));`

1. And then you can get the url for ajax using $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], $folder and wp-blog-header.php like this:

`$ajax_url = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'/'.$folder.'/wp-blog-header.php';`